# Qt c++ and Qml signal and slot connection

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick-designer

I have created a qt widget for my project. Button, signal and slot, thread everything working properly also I have taken output.

Dialog.h

```
public slots:

    void startThread();
    void stopThread();
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
void  Dialog:: startThread(){

    if(!startThreadflag){

    this->ui->Start_2->setEnabled(false);
    this->ui-> Stop_2->setEnabled(true);

    startThreadflag = true;
    stopThreadflag = false;

    }
}

void Dialog:: stopThread(){

    if(!stopThreadflag){
            cout << "Closing threads"<< endl;

        this->ui->Start_2->setEnabled(true);
        this->ui->Stop_2->setEnabled(false);

        stopThreadflag= true;
        startThreadflag = false;
    }
}

void Dialog::on_Close_clicked()
{
    cout<<"close_clicked"<<endl;

    this->close();
}
```

For creating dashboard purpose I have developed same ui in qml, signal and slot everything connected when I press the button signal and slot connected. But I don't know how to connect the label button, set enabled.

that is qt widget code. below that dialog.cpp and qml

dialog.cpp

```
void Dialog::startThread()
{
    cout<<"Start Clicked"<<endl;

    emit startbuttonclicked();
}

void Dialog::stopThread()
{
    cout<<"Stop Clicked"<<endl;

    emit stopbuttonclicked();
}
```

dashboard.qml : (Like all buttons same)

```
               Item {
              Dialog { 
                 id: dialog1;
                  }
                 Button {
                     x:220
                     y:295
                     text: "Start"
                     onClicked: { dialog1.startThread() }
                     }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifies that type of variable the function returns
main() must return an integer

No scaling before QApplication is instantiated.

```
     QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf");
    app.setFont(QFont("DejaVu Sans"));
// Now I am using Dialog like context property in qml
// qmlRegisterType<Dialog>("CustomExtensions",1,0,"Dialog");
Dialog dlg;
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

// Now in qml we can access to dlg by "dialogObj" name

engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dialogObj", &dlg);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/dashboard.qml")));

//QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:/qml/dashboard.qml"));       ``
```

Using this you can access Qt signal and slot with qml

Comment: Ya exactly, thanks for your answer. In the main function, I can use this, but from qt c++ is it possible to access slots ?

Comment: yes @JerwinPrabuA you can access from qml signal to qt slot using invariant

Comment: ya i have tried, now i can access from qml to qt c++. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your QML file to enable/disable your label

```
function enableStart_2(enable)
{
    Start_2.enabled = enable;
}
```

Then you need to connect your Qt signal to the QML slot like e.g. (connector inherits `QObject`)
`QObject::connect(&connector, SIGNAL(enableStart_2(QVariant)), window, SLOT(enableStart_2(QVariant)));`

This is how you emit the signal to your QML slot
`emit enableStart_2(true);`

**UPDATE**

As an example: Your

```
onClicked: { dialog1.startThread() }
```

must be something like

```
onClicked: { startThread() }
```

with `startThread()` being a QML signal defined in your QML file like `signal startThread()`.

You need to connect your QML signal to a slot in your C++ code:

```
QObject::connect(window, SIGNAL(startThread()), &foo, SLOT(onStartThread()));
```

Now you need to define a slot inside of your Foo class:

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void onStartThread(void);
};
```

In the definition of function `onStartThread` you start your thread.

Comment: I have tried but same output i got. I have connected with signal and slot. In qt widget we can use   this->ui->Start_2->setEnabled(true); in dialog.cpp. In qml How to connect using source file ?

Comment: Where are you stuck?
Have you seen [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html), especially section 'Connecting to QML Signals'?

Comment: Ya I saw that. Connecting to QML Signals

Comment: And did it help you? If not, where are you stuck?

Comment: Problem is not in signal and slot. I have connected signal and slot, when I press the start button from dashboard, It was reached to source file and signal slot connected also printed. (Question)Now I want set enable other label.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for that. using his can enable the specific button.

```
 Connections {
               target:dialogObj
               onStart_2EnabledChanged: {
               startBtn.enabled = state
              }
                onStop_2EnabledChanged: {
                stopBtn.enabled = state
              }
         }
```